# How to open an excel file protected with password using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

How can I open an excel file that is protected by password using Selenium??

I am able to interact with any other excel that does not have a password and I now how to do it.

This is the code that I already have to access excel file without password:

```
    File src = new File("C:/Users/.../.../.../Credentials Automation.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFSheet sheet2 = wb.getSheetAt(1);
```

Comment: This is absolutely NOT about Selenium, selenium-webdriver or automation!

Comment: probably for you it is not, but for me it is!!!

I am creating an automation using selenium webdriver, and I need to open an excel file which request a password before opening it. 

My question: is there a way to do it using selenium. 

If you know how to read, the tags above are about "Java", "Excel" and just after, "Selenium"

all the code above are inside of my Selenium Script, so yes, I am using it with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to the apache-poi library (the one that you are using in your code snipped), which allows the manipulation of the excel files. Selenium, per say, has no functionality for this.

---

### Maven: Apache-poi

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or manualy download the jar file from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad/5.0.0

### Solution

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Decryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void openProtectedExcelFile() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        String excelFilePath = "E:/Credentials Automation.xlsx";
        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new File(excelFilePath));
        EncryptionInfo encryptionInfo = new EncryptionInfo(fileSystem);
        Decryptor decryptor = Decryptor.getInstance(encryptionInfo);
        decryptor.verifyPassword("selenium"); //pass the password in here
        InputStream dataStream = decryptor.getDataStream(fileSystem);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFSheet sheet2 = wb.getSheetAt(1);

        XSSFRow row1 = sheet1.getRow(0);
        System.out.println(row1.getCell(0));
        wb.close();
        
    }
}
```

[image]